# access exoplayer element in component in Nativescript angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, exoplayer

I'm using Nativescript and using [exoplayer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-exoplayer) component, I couldn't find anything how to access this in component, for e.g I want to change the **src** in the same page (e.g we have different quality that we want to change the src, we should destroy player and reinitilize it with new src), get some events like play, error and ... and maybe have my custom action buttons

I also tried this:

```
@ViewChild(Video)
private player: Video;
```

but it's undefined

this is my view code:

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical" width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="black">
    <exoplayer *ngIf="is_loaded" id="player"
               [src]="episode.link
               playbackReady="change_player_quality"
               autoplay="true"
               height="300"
               class="exoplayer"></exoplayer>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the result my self so I let you know what happened,
I made view child like this:

```
@ViewChild('player') player: ElementRef;
```

And I added a tag to the player in view:

```
<exoplayer id="player" [src]="video.link" autoplay="true" height="300" class="exoplayer" #player></exoplayer>
```

then when I want to work with player API or change **src** I get object like this:

```
this.player.nativeElement.src = 'file.mp4';
```

or destroy:

```
this.player.nativeElement.destroy();
```

I hope it helps you

good luck